Object moves between identical keyframes
I'm a total beginner in Blender and I have what I believe 2 identical keyframes I added by selecting the object and pressing I.

Why is the position of the object moving between the keyframes?


You need to check the Graph Editor, you have the same X, Y and Z location values at frame 33 and 93 but the curve is going up and down:


thank you for the answer, i have to wrap my head around this. both my keyframes have the same X Y Z coordinates and there's no other keyframe between them, so I don't really see where this movement is coming from.

I've edited my answer

oooh i see, got it, thank you!
